# Retrieving records by collection IDs, LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections, many-to-many

I want to retrieve the rows if the Id exists in the collection of Ids I'm passing.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
var typeOfNeedIds = [1,2,3];
var query = (from up in _context.UserNeeds
             .Include(u => u.UserNeedTypes).ThenInclude(ut => ut.TypeOfNeed)
                where (typeOfNeedIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ||
                       typeOfNeedIds.All(id => up.UserNeedTypes.Select(t => t.TypeOfNeedId).Contains(id)))
                select up).AsNoTracking();
```

I've also tried

```
typeOfNeedIds.Any(id => up.UserNeedTypes.Any(t => t.TypeOfNeedId == id))
```

But none worked.

What's wrong with my code? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `collection.Where(item => typeOfNeedIds.Contains(item.Id));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all `UserNeeds`, where `UserNeedTypes` contains at least one of `typeOfNeedIds`.

```
var typeOfNeedIds = [1,2,3];
var query = _context.UserNeeds.Where(un =>
                  un.UserNeedTypes.Any(unp =>
                      typeOfNeedIfs.Contains(unp.TypeOfNeedId)
                  )
            )
            .Include(u => u.UserNeedTypes)
            .ThenInclude(ut => ut.TypeOfNeed)
            .AsNoTracking();
```